# LightGBM GPU Support for MacBook M1 and M2 Chips

Tags: python, apple-m1, lightgbm, apple-m2

I understand that the CPU version of LightGBM on MacBook M1 and M2 chips is currently not officially supported and can only be obtained through Conda-forge. However, I would like to know if there have been any updates or announcements regarding the availability of GPU support for LightGBM on these chips.

Comment: I can see based on the discussions on github, the issue/feature request is still open and they don't seem to have capacity or priority over m1,m2 gpu support.

Answer (score 0):

Following @sastaengineer comment, there are some issues still opened ([availability of binary python package for M1](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/5328), [installation errors](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/5700) or [performance between M1 and M2](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/5775)). These issues have helpful answers from maintainers, but the best solution seems to be using conda, `conda install -c conda-forge lightgbm`.